# UI-Router transition exit hook never fires

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

In this [Plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/gyW08ObHH39CA0fbqiE3/), I register an `onExit` hook on the [`Transition`](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/latest/classes/transition.transition-1.html), but it doesn't ever get called.  It's slightly ambiguous in the [docs](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/latest/classes/transition.transition-1.html#onexit) whether the hook is registered globally (for any state change) or specifically for that transition.  Either way, I'd expect it to be called at some point.

I know I can register a global `onExit` hook on the [`TransitionService`](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/latest/classes/transition.transitionservice.html), but my use-case is to only register it for the current `Transition`.